# Consistent address values for %i, but not %p

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a beginner trying to get to grips with pointers. In the below, the %p value for 't' is unique when compared to 'p' and '&n', whereas the %i value for 't' is the same as 'p' and '&n'.

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 50;
    int *p = &n;
    int t = &n;
    // using %p below
    printf("%p\n", p);
    printf("%p\n", &n);
    printf("%p\n", t);
    // using %i below
    printf("%i\n", p);
    printf("%i\n", &n);
    printf("%i\n", t);
}
```

Example output:

```
0x7ffc3f503cd8
0x7ffc3f503cd8
0x3f503cd8
1062223064
1062223064
1062223064
```

I think I am comfortable with %i being the same (although a clear explanation of this would be really appreciated too), and I'm aware that I haven't declared '*t', and so I was wondering what %p for 't' represents here?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. What you're doing here is a whole load of *undefined behaviour*. `int t = &n` is not going to happen on a 64-bit platform. `%p` on an `int` is also undefined.

Comment: Hint: Does `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)`?

Comment: Ah, okay. I was using an online compiler for convenience, but can now see this will not compile in VS Code. Although undefined, is there an underlying rationale to explain the consistency of %i, and not %p?

Comment: I'm not sure how you don't get from your own example that `p` and `&n` are pointers, and `t` is not. And secondly what you expect `%p` to represent when the argument is *not* a pointer.

Comment: @Abedbeginnings The `%i` implies casting the arguments to `int`, so they all show the same values, because they are all effectively `&n` being cast to `int`.

Comment: Sometimes things that are undefined behaviour end up that way by sheer chance, and other times it's because that particular compiler handles things a certain way. They're still undefined, which means on another compiler you may get completely different results. There's nothing you can really draw from this other than that's how that *particular* compiler seems to work.

Comment: Remember your 64-bit pointer gets truncated to fit in a 32-bit `int`, so you're only going to get the tail-end of that value. You cannot expect to get 64 bits of data from a 32-bit value. You're likely lucky here, as that `int` might have other junk in it if you had `int t = &n; int u = 0xdeadbeef;` where the remaining 4 bytes now have values instead of coincidentally zeroed out stack space.

Comment: If you want to store a pointer as an integer, you should use `intptr_t`. Or better, `uintptr_t`. Those are guaranteed to be able to store a `void *` without losing info.

Comment: Appreciate all the comments, all of which have been useful.

Comment: @Cheatah I was aware that 't' is not a pointer, but it didn't prevent me from satisfying my curiosity to see what would happen.

Comment: @tadman thank you for the clarification — I wasn't wise enough to realise the truncation.

Comment: @HAL9000 that's right, I was able to test and validate that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The line

```
int t = &n;
```

is not valid ISO C. It is not legal to assign a pointer type to an integer type without a cast. What your compiler is probably doing is ignoring this error and applying an implicit cast. However, on most 64-bit platforms, an `int` only has a size of 32 bits, whereas a pointer has a size of 64 bits. Therefore, on those platforms, an `int` is not able to store an entire pointer. This will cause the value to be truncated, by removing the most significant bits of the value.

In your case, the address of `n` has the following hexadecimal value:

```
0x00007ffc3f503cd8
```

Truncating the most significant 32 bits of this 64 bit value will yield the following value:

```
0x3f503cd8
```

Therefore, this is the value that is being assigned to `t`.

Also, the lines

```
printf("%p\n", t);
```

and

```
printf("%i\n", &n);
```

are invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because

- the `%p` conversion format specifier requires an argument of type pointer, but you are instead supplying an argument of type `int`.
- the `%i` conversion format specifier requires an argument of type `int`, but you are instead supplying it a pointer.

On most platforms, this mixing of integer and pointer types will work, as long as the size of the pointer has the same size as the integer data type. However, as already mentioned, on most 64-bit platforms, an `int` is 32 bits whereas a pointer is 64 bits, so in the case of

```
printf("%i\n", &n);
```

the value will probably be truncated, and in the case of

```
printf("%p\n", t);
```

it will attempt to print a 64-bit value, although only a 32-bit value exists. Therefore, `printf` will probably attempt to read an extra 32 bits from memory from whatever address is next to the value that was passed to the function. In your case, these extra 32 bits all happen to have the value `0`. The meaning of these extra 32 bits may depend on the [function calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) that your platform is using.

If you want to ensure that the integer data type is sufficiently large to store a pointer, then I recommend that you use the [`uintptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) data type (which is probably just an alias for `long` or `long long`, depending on your platform). Note that you must `#include <stdint.h>` if you want to use `uintptr_t`. However, generally, there is no reason to use an integer data type for storing a memory address.

Comment: Re “The line … is not valid ISO C.”: It is in fact *conforming* code as the C standard defines it. Stop telling people the standard prohibits things, other than a very few things such as `#error`. The C standard specifies a base language that is intended to be extended. It defines things in the base language but does not make most things beyond that invalid. (Wording in the standard about constraints is notional rhetoric for specifying what is defined, not actual constraints on the programmer.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: When I use that wording, I mean that it is a constraint violation according to [§6.7.9 ¶11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p11) and §6.5.16.1 ¶1 of the ISO C11 standard, so that a conforming compiler is not required to accept the code. However, you are correct that a conforming compiler is not required to reject the code, either. It is only required to provide a "diagnostic message" according to §5.1.1.3 ¶1 of the standard. I believe that it is appropriate to refer to code as "not valid", if the code requires a diagnostic message and may be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to explain what you saw in your rather badly damaged program, I'm going to present a similar but less-damaged and hopefully more-meaningful program.  ([Andreas Wenzel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73922351/consistent-address-values-for-i-but-not-p/73922494#73922494) does a good job of explaining the behavior you saw in the original program.)

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 50;
    int *p = &n;
    int t = &n;     /* wrong, but let's see what it does */

    printf("n: addr = %p, contents = %d\n", &n, n);
    printf("p: addr = %p, contents = %p, indirect = %d\n", &p, p, *p);
    printf("t: addr = %p, contents = %x\n", &t, t);
}
```

When I run this on my machine, the output is

```
n: addr = 0x7ffeec9f49ac, contents = 50
p: addr = 0x7ffeec9f49a0, contents = 0x7ffeec9f49ac, indirect = 50
t: addr = 0x7ffeec9f499c, contents = ec9f49ac
```

Let's examine this output in detail:

1. All three variables — `n`, `p`, and `t` — have similar addresses (`0x7ffeec9f49xx`) , since they're all local variables, next to each other in `main`'s stack frame.
2. The contents of the pointer `p` indeed match the address of variable `n`.
3. The value pointed to by pointer `p` is indeed `n`'s value (50).
4. Although `t` is not a pointer variable, it does contain *part of* `n`'s address: `0xec9f49ac`.

The reason `t` can't hold an entire pointer value is that, on my machine at least, type `int` is a 32-bit type while pointers are 64 bits.  That's why it's important to use real pointer variables to hold pointer values, and to print the pointer values using `%p`, not some format designed for ordinary integers.

One thing you shouldn't do is that line

```
int t = &n;
```

Here we're explicitly jamming a pointer into an `int`.  On my machine, at least, my compiler warns me about this mistake, saying `warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'int *'`.

Notice that I have used `%d` to print `n`'s value, if for no other reason than that I don't like `%i`.

There's a slight error in the code I've presented: theoretically, `%p` is only for printing pointers of type `void *`, not necessarily other pointer types.  Strictly speaking I should have written

```
printf("n: addr = %p, contents = %d\n", (void *)&n, n);
printf("p: addr = %p, contents = %p, indirect = %d\n", (void *)&p, (void *)p, *p);
printf("t: addr = %p, contents = %x\n", (void *)&t, t);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are expected types for arguments corresponding to the `%p` and `%i` directives, those are `void *` and `int`. While some promotions do occur when passing arguments to a variadic function (such as `printf`), those don't involve converting `int *` to `void *` or `int`. If the argument passed (after the default argument promotions) is not of the expected type, the behaviour is undefined.

That is, the following statements all cause behaviour that is purely coincidental on your system, may do something different on other systems, or may change on your system to something entirely undesirable (such as crashes or vulnerabilities):

```
printf("%p\n", p);
printf("%p\n", &n);
printf("%p\n", t);
printf("%i\n", &n);
```

To resolve these issues we could add explicit casts:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) p);
printf("%p\n", (void *) &n);
printf("%p\n", (void *) t);
printf("%i\n", (int) &n);
```

The output would still be coincidental for your system, due to the way `%p` is specified to function (the wording is rather vague; pointers aren't required to print as numeric) and some implementation-defined aspects behind converting pointers to `int` (could cause undefined behaviour on some systems), thus the suggestion to use wider types like `uintptr_t` (which has a `"%"PRIuPTR` directive, from `#include <inttypes.h>`) or `uintmax_t` (see below).

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 50;
    printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t) n);
    printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t) &n);
}
```

Comment: Re “purely coincidental on your system”: No, it is not; the behaviors arise from compiler and ABI design and not purely out of coincidence.

Comment: @EricPostpischil in the sense that it's not required to be documented, and even if it is documented, that's not required to match the behaviour... There are legal consequences for writing non-compliant code that "coincidentally" fails. I suggest reviewing the tag wiki for resources; your ABI design isn't relevant here, at least not until you tag it in.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "This tag should be used with general questions concerning the C language, as defined in the ISO 9899 standard (the latest version, 9899:2018, unless otherwise specified — also tag version-specific requests with c89, c99, c11, etc)."